# Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Response'

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> ERROR Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Response'

I tried some solutions from several sides but none of them are working.
Is there any way to solve this..............

-------CODE FOR FETCH DATA FROM FIREBASE------------------

```
    getRooms(){
    this.http.get('https://ng-hotel-book.firebaseio.com/rooms.json')
    .subscribe(
        (response: Response) => {
            const rooms: Room[] = response.json();
            this.roomService.setRooms(rooms);
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about firebase, but you can put the console.log for just response and check what properties you have to access the data as it seems json is not a function itself for Response type

Comment: what is the angular version?

Comment: Write a title that summarizes the specific problem. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Angular 4+, use `HttpClient` for making the get call.

Then this should help -

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
.
.
.

constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

getRooms(){
    this.http.get<Room[]>('https://ng-hotel-book.firebaseio.com/rooms.json')
    .subscribe(
        (rooms: Room[]) => {
            this.roomService.setRooms(rooms);
        }
    )
}
```